# show and hide pic when click button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a picture on when I click a button(on)and when I click button (off) will hide picture on and display picture off

I have this code the javascript runs in button(on)show picture on and button(off) hide picture on
so I need to show picture off when click button off and hide when click button on.

```
 <button id="show-image-button"  style="--clr:#0FF0FC"><span>on</span><i></i></button>
  <br>
  <button  onclick="myFunction()"  style="--clr:#0FF0FC"><span>off</span><i></i></button>
  <br>
  <img id="my-image"  src="pump on.gif" alt="anim" style=" text-align: center;  justify-content:center;display: none;width:130px;height:130px;">
  <br>
  <img  src="pump off.png" alt="anima" style="display: none;width:120px;height:100px;">
  <br>
  
    <script>
   
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("my-image").style.visibility = "hidden";
      
        
      }
      const showImageButton = document.getElementById("show-image-button");
      const myImage = document.getElementById("my-image"); 
      showImageButton.addEventListener("click", () => { 
         myImage.style.display = "block"; 
  
      }
      );
   
    </script>
```

Comment: I would suggest toggling classes rather than inline style. Also there are plenty of tutorials on the web showing how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

hi try to use the if statement and then use the test function on your button you can both the arrow function or the regular function method

```js
let show = true  
let test = () => {
   if (show == true) {
     document.getElementById("sth").style.display = "none"
      show = false
    } 
 else {
     document.getElementById("sth").style.display = "block"
      show = true
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="sth" src="something"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simplified** function approach

```js
function myFunction(val) {
     
     const imgHolder = document.getElementById("my-image");
     const images = {
          off : "pump off.png", 
          on: "pump on.png"
     }


   if(!val) { imgHolder.classList.add('d-none'); return };
    
     imgHolder.classList.remove('d-none')
     imgHolder.setAttribute('src', images[val])
     imgHolder.setAttribute('alt', images[val]) // Optional
 
 }
```

```css
.d-none { display: none; }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('on')">
  <span>on</span>
</button>
<br />
<button onclick="myFunction('off')">
   <span>off</span>
</button>

<br />

<img id="my-image" src="pump on.gif" alt="anim ON" class="d-none" />
```